# How to connect a library from a package to a Makefile

Tags: makefile

There is a jsoncpp package, I use it in the program, I try to connect it to the project, but it does not connect.

Project structure:

- client.json
- cross-build-make.sh
- main.cpp
- main.hpp
- Makefile

There is a Makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

JSONCPP_INCLUDE := $(shell pkg-config --cflags jsoncpp)
JSONCPP_LIB := $(shell pkg-config --libs jsoncpp)

TARGET=my_program

SRCS=main.cpp

OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(JSONCPP_LIB) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(JSONCPP_INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Launching the program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I/usr/include/jsoncpp -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ljsoncpp main.o -o my_program
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function «main»:
main.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to «Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to «Json::operator>>(std::istream&, Json::Value&)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to «Json::Value::operator[](char const*)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to «Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to «Json::Value::operator[](char const*)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to «Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to «Json::Value::~Value()»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:25: my_program] Error 1
rm -f main.o my_program
```

I tried to write the path with my hands, it turned out the same as with automatic search.

In the first case, it did not automatically find the path to the library, so in the second case I explicitly specified the path:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

JSONCPP_INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/

JSONCPP_LIB=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ljsoncpp

TARGET=my_program

SRCS=main.cpp

OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(JSONCPP_LIB) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(JSONCPP_INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Launching the program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I/usr/include/ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ljsoncpp 
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function «main»:
main.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to «Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to «Json::operator>>(std::istream&, Json::Value&)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to «Json::Value::operator[](char const*)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to «Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to «Json::Value::operator[](char const*)»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to «Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to «Json::Value::~Value()»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:25: my_program] Error 1
rm -f main.o my_program
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have just put it in another place:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

# Путь к заголовочным файлам jsoncpp
JSONCPP_INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/

# Путь к библиотеке jsoncpp
JSONCPP_LIB=-L/usr/lib/ -ljsoncpp

# JSONCPP_INCLUDE := $(shell pkg-config --cflags jsoncpp)
# JSONCPP_LIB := $(shell pkg-config --libs jsoncpp)

# Имя исполняемого файла
TARGET=my_program

# Список исходных файлов
SRCS=main.cpp

# Список объектных файлов
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET) $(JSONCPP_LIB)
    

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(JSONCPP_INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```